# Unable to run C++ files using code runner on VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am unable to run my CPP files on VS Code through code runner extension.
It happened after I tried to activate conda as python interpretator on vs code.

Here is the error it shows after running a C++ file(It shows the same error on running other cpp files as well)

> PS C:\Users\hp> g++ *.cpp -o job_queue && ./job_queue.exe
>   At line:1 char:24
>   + g++ *.cpp -o job_queue && ./job_queue.exe
>   +                        ~~
>   The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],                               ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

settings.json

```
{
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,

"timeline.pageSize": 1,
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"code-runner.executorMap": {

    "cpp": "g++ *.cpp -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",


},
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"code-runner.languageIdToFileExtensionMap": {


},
"code-runner.defaultLanguage": "C++",
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "",
```

}

Comment: A lot of people have trouble with this. How wedded to using Visual Studio Code are you? It takes more than a little finicky configuration to make it work, and if you're already trying to learn C++, why fight with learning to wrangle an IDE at the same time?  See if you can find an all-in-one pre-configured IDE, a free community release of Visual Studio, for example.

Comment: Report to its extension developer(s) please, https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues

Comment: Looks like there is an issue open about this on [code runner's github](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/491). The easy fix seems to be using `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "powershell.exe"`

Comment: Visual Studio Code is simply not an IDE. You can use it like one after some tinkering but it's not intended to "one-click debug" anything.

Comment: What is the appeal of VS Code on Windows? I see lots of beginners using it and it does seem a bit too complex for a beginner. Visual Studio seems a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
"cpp": "cd $dir ; g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe ; .\\$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation to this piece of code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I was running the code with code runner extension in vscode and it ran the code in P S and was throwing errors. then i found this. I tried many of the codes and this one worked fine for my case. I honestly dont know the inner workings. https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/248

Answer (score 0):

```
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -o $fileNameWithoutExt *.cpp && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

This worked for me. Edit the codeRunner executorMap JSON file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

If you are a beginner in programming and learning to code in C++ on a windows machine, i recommend to start with a more simpler ide like turbo C++ or dev C++, etc. After this you can switch to codeblocks ide or if you want, directly to vs code.

Coming to your problem, i also faced the same problem on my macbook(i also write C++ in vs code on mac) and i managed to fix it by just reinstalling the extension, however since you are on windows, it should be much easier for you to figure it out.
Just do some youtube research about the installation and it should be fine.